# How to Clear Python Output Programatically in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

This question is specific to Google Colaboratory, while some solutions may work in a normal Python interperter, Google Colaboratory does not seem to allow me to programatically clear the Python interpreter output.

Solutions that I have already tried that do not work:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
os.system('clear')
!cls
!clear
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`from IPython.display import clear_output
clear_output()`

This is useful to me.

Answer (score 11):

```
from google.colab import output



  output.clear()
```

Answer (score -1):

This snippet will halt the current Python runtime and reconnect to a fresh one. (Your filesystem will remain intact.)

```
import os
os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
```

Comment: This does not fit my use case unfortunately, it requires that the runtime continues executing, after the screen is cleared.