# How do you clear Google Colab's output periodically

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection-api

I am using Google Colab to train an object detection model, using the tensorflow object detection api. When I run the cell `train.py`, it keeps printing diegnostic output. After 30 minutes or so the browser crashes, because of the high number of lines printed in the cell's output.

Is there any script which one can use to clear the output periodically (say every 30 min) instead of manually pressing the `clear output button`?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions given in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52751413/how-to-clear-python-output-programatically-in-google-colaboratory

Comment: Where do I run the python codes specified in the above link?

Answer (score 7):

You can use google.colab.output.clear()

```py
from google.colab import output

for i in range(100):
  print(i)
  # do something
  if i%10 == 0:
    output.clear()
```

Comment: I need to clear the output in the last cell of my google colab notebook[(link here)](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1q2mk0swEhxfbFtY6NDBky6o3NlRbh7Sp#scrollTo=OTK1MS1eVl9E). Can you please tell me where to use this code to clear the output of the last cell

Comment: You can put `output.clear()` at the end of the last cell.

Comment: I already tried that and it does not work. It is because the `python train.py` cell keeps printing output to the console as long as it is running and hence the `output.clear()` command will never be executed

Answer (score 4):

I actually figured out a way to solve this issue.
Enclose the line(s) of code whose output you are trying to suppress within the following lines

```
from IPython.utils import io
with io.capture_output() as captured:
    # Enter code here
```

In my case, the cell had the following code

```
from IPython.utils import io
with io.capture_output() as captured:
     !python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=/content/drive/My\ Drive/ocr_resized_train_checkpoints/ --pipeline_config_path=/content/frcnn_inception.config
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: it really helped me a lot, thanks! I was starting to think that I was the only one having this problem.

Comment: As it is being run as a shell command you can also use shell redirection `> /dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

Hi Jitesh Malipeddi,

So I ran into the same issue you are having and although this is not the most elegant way, I have come up with a hack to make this work. What I did was use the thread module and with an array loop a bunch of numbers into the array and thread my output.clear() function along with training my model. I just came up with this tonight so I will be working on a better version of this using the time module, because this version is hard coded.

```
    from google.colab import output
    import threading

    #holds time in secs.
    times = []

    #this 6000 represents 100 mins
    for y in range(6000):
        #every 5mins
        if y %300==0:
        #append this number
        times.append(y)
    else:
        continue
    #this function holds are output.clear()
    def gfg():
        output.clear()
    #for the length of the array times
    for x in range(len(times)):

        #start threading with the Timer module each element of the array
        #and when times[x] arrives use function gfg to clear console.
        timer = threading.Timer(times[x],gfg)
        timer.start()


    #your darknet training command 
    !./darknetdetectortrain
```

My next version will be able to continue indefinitely till the work environment blows up or you stop the train. FYI if you run this script and you want to make changes to the time and how long the script takes to clear the output, reset the run time because you will start to have issues.

Comment: Hi, I actually figured out another simpler workaround to this. Please check the answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: Nice, I tried your example for my yolov3 model and I think it was working its just that you can't see any output which makes it hard to determine when to stop training.

Answer (score 0):

`%%capture`

works as well

```
%%capture
!python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=/content/drive/My\ Drive/ocr_resized_train_checkpoints/ --pipeline_config_path=/content/frcnn_inception.config
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution, but you could also specify your `verbose` parameter in your fit method to 0 to get no output, or to 2 to get a reduced output.

And you can use TensorBoard to still see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I set up a shortcut

<kbd>**Ctrl+Shift+C**</kbd>

that clears all output.
Just set it under **shortcuts**.