# how do i clear the output screen or terminal in python? os.system("clear") and os.system("cls") did not work. (In google collaboratory)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am trying to design a game in Python. Where it will take inputs from five users.But i do not want the user's to know each others inputs. So i would like to erase the screen after taking a input from the user and then ask the next user.Is there any way to accomplish this?

I tried taking in inputs but the terminal shows the previous line revealing the input given by the previous user. Is there any way to hide it

```
User1=int(input("enter your number Player1"))
User2=int(input("enter your number Player2"))
User3=int(input("enter your number Player3"))
User4=int(input("enter your number Player4"))
User5=int(input("enter your number Player5"))
```

[image: input result]

It is displaying the input taken by the previous User. I need a way to hide it.

I have tried using `import os`
and using `os.system('cls')`
but that did not work.(I was Using google colab)

```
import os

User1=int(input("enter your number Player1 "))
os.system('cls')
User2=int(input("enter your number Player2 "))
os.system('cls')
User3=int(input("enter your number Player3 "))
os.system('cls')
User4=int(input("enter your number Player4 "))
os.system('cls')
User5=int(input("enter your number Player5 "))
```

[image: input result]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to clear the screen in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810537/how-to-clear-the-screen-in-python)

Comment: I have tried using os.system('cls') and os.system('clear') but it didnt work in google colab

Comment: How about this then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52751413/how-to-clear-python-output-programatically-in-google-colaboratory

Answer (score -1):

Try using `os.system("clear")` instead. That should do the trick. Google Colab uses linux and `cls` is for windows but `clear` is for macos and linux.

Comment: Questions as basic as this have usually already been asked and answered. The correct action is to find the pre-existing question, and flag / vote to close this one as a duplicate. Don't answer duplicate questions!

Comment: My bad, will definitely do that in the future

Comment: https://www.grepper.com/tpc/clear+console+in+google+collab